# Complexity of Subset-Sum when the target sum is a constant

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

The Subset-Sum decision problem is:

Given a set of n non-negative integers S, is there a subset of S that sum to k?
If S and k are inputs, the problem is known to be NP-Complete.

What about the case when k is not an input but a constant?
Is the problem still NP-Complete?

My thoughts are that if k is given, since the integers are all non-negative, we only need to consider subsets of at most k elements (ignoring elements that are zero). 
That means we only need to consider at most $n^k$ possibilities which is polynomial.
So, the problem is not NP-Complete. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Even better, there is a dynamical programming solution that uses $O(nk)$ steps.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting here for posterity, as this result is high in the search results for subset-sum.  Subset-sum is absolutely NP-complete.

The missing information here is that $O(n^k)$ and $O(nk)$ are both exponential runtimes.  The definition of NP-complete specifies runtimes in terms of the number of bits in the input, not in terms of single integer inputs like $k$.

Note that it requires $\log k$ bits to specify $k$.  Therefore if you 'spend' n bits on the array input and m bits on specifying $k$, the runtime is $O(nk) = O(n2^m)$.